# Homework - One Server serves multiple Clients with Semaphores and Shared Memory

Tags: c, concurrency, semaphore, shared-memory

Hello everyone here am I with another homework issue. I have to write a Client and a Server program so that the Server (with shared memory and semaphores) can communicate with the Client. A client gets data from the stdin sends it to the server, the server sorts it and sends it back. The problem is that the server has to serve multiple clients and I wrote it so it could serve only one. If someone could give me that mind push how to achieve that would be nice.

here are my client :

[Client](https://c.privatepaste.com/7590dd1f30)

and server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define SEMKEY1 6666
#define SEMKEY2 7777
#define SHMKEY  8888
#define HSIZE    128

union semun {
  int val;                   /*value for SETVAL*/
  struct semid_ds *buf;      /*buffer for IPC_STAT, IPC_SET*/
  unsigned short int *array; /*array for getall, setall*/
  struct seminfo *__buf;     /*buffer for IPC_INFO*/
};

int P(int semid){
  struct sembuf occupy;
  int res;

  occupy.sem_num  =  0;
  occupy.sem_op   = -1;
  occupy.sem_flg  =  0;
  res = semop(semid, &occupy, 1);
  if(res < 0){
    fprintf(stderr,"P() Failed");
    exit(1);
  }
  return res;  
}

int V(int semid){
  struct sembuf release;
  int res;
  release.sem_num  =  0;
  release.sem_op   =  1;
  release.sem_flg  =  0;

  res = semop(semid, &release, 1);
  if(res < 0){
    fprintf(stderr,"V() failed");
    exit(1);
  }
  return res;  
}

int getSem(int key){
  int semid;
  int errno;

  if((semid = semget(key, 1, 0)) < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "getSem failed for key %d because %d \n ", key, errno);
    exit(1);    
  }
  return semid;
}

/*STRUCKT die fuer die SHARED MEMORY benutzt wird*/
typedef struct srtelem {
  long elem;
  int flg;
}SMSTRCKT;

int long_comp(const void *a, const void *b){
  const int *ai = (const int *) a;
  const int *bi = (const int *) b;

  return *ai - *bi; 
}

void print_hangar(long *hangar, int i){
  int j;

  for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
    printf("%ld \n", *(hangar+j));
  }
}

int main(){
  int semid1, semid2, shm_id, count;
  int errno, index;
  SMSTRCKT *shmptr;
  long hangar[HSIZE];

  /*Semaphore hollen*/
  semid1 = getSem(SEMKEY1);
  semid2 = getSem(SEMKEY2);
  count = 0;
  index = 0;
  printf("\t**SERVER**\n");

  /*Shared memory anlegen*/
  if((shm_id = shmget(SHMKEY, sizeof(SMSTRCKT), 066)) < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "SHMGET failed because of %d\n",errno);
    exit(1);  
  }

  /*Shared memory anhaengen*/
  if((shmptr = (SMSTRCKT *) shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0)) == (SMSTRCKT*) -1){
    fprintf(stderr,"SHMAT failed because of %d\n", errno);
    exit(1);    
  }

/*Get date from the Client*/
   while((shmptr->flg) == 1){
      P(semid2);
      if(shmptr->flg != 0){
    printf("elem %d \n ",(int) shmptr->elem);
    *(hangar+count) = shmptr->elem;
    count++;
      }  
      V(semid1);
    }
    qsort(hangar,count, sizeof(long),long_comp);

    /*Send the result to the Client*/
    while(index < count){
      P(semid1);

      shmptr->elem = *(hangar+index);
      /*printf(" elem %ld  index %d\n", shmptr->elem, index);*/
      ++index;

      V(semid2);
    }

    P(semid1);
    shmptr->flg++;
    V(semid2);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: try to use tab-key or at least 4 spaces for indentation

Comment: Extra-push: Stop and consider WHY you're using semaphores. If there is only one client, what is the point? Semaphores are a tricky concept and having two or more clients (or two or more servers) really forces you to understand HOW they work.

Comment: @Andy, no, do **not** use Tab key in SO editor (unless you want the indentation of your code messed up, that is). Only spaces please.

Comment: @Robin, I removed the tremendous amount of empty and commented lines from your code (making it about 50% shorter) and formatted it according to SO standards. Please next time trim it yourself - the longer code you post, the less the chance of someone actually reading it. Moreover, don't use `<pre>` and `<code>` tags - just indent your code by 4 spaces, or use the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks for the help, I will.
@aqua : Well the semaphores are there to prevent a process from accessing something that is in the critical section when another process is already using it. In my example don't let the client access the shared memory before it is free (not used by another client or server)

Comment: Is this an "academic exercise" in which you have to implement it as such - because it is certainly not a great way to do this type of client-server communication. If it *is* (and I assume it is) - than by your own explanation, the server can't "handle" more than one client at a time - because only one client can use the shared memory at a given time. Therefore, the semaphore is what inherently gates the clients - and therefore the server only handles one client at a time. If the whole idea of the exercise is that you only have ONE shared memory segment that all clients use...

Comment: @Brad: Right on the nose. Yes he can only serve one client at the time. Wit my current server program I can read get the inputs of two clients from the shared memory but when I send it it only send to one client and the other is trapped in an endless loop (because of the while condition).

Comment: Don't needlessly typedef - if something has a type already, it doesn't need a typedef.  Also, FULLY UPPERCASE NAMES are by convention used for #defines and macros.  It is accordingly unwise to use this convention for typedef names; it will confuse readers.  Finally, it is usual to put all non-code entities (typedefs, defines, etc) in a header file (although for here, where we can't easily display multiple files, at the top of the file is the best that can be done).  This saves people having to search for them through the code.

Comment: @Blank: Thank you Blank, I am pretty new to C and learning. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: I am having a very hard time following your code. I would advise putting in many more comments - to the point where you are describing everything you're doing and why. I don't know why you are using two different semaphores, and on each P and V you seem to be acquiring one, and releasing the other. Also, *where* is the endless loop you are seeing? What are the values you expect? What are you seeing? Much of this is proper investigation, debugging, and that means commenting to the point where it makes sense to you, and others!

Comment: The two semaphores are there so that when the client is finished with the input he lock himself and waits for the server to put that input into an array and then the server locks itself and waits for the client to input again. If I had used one semaohore it wouldn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to read about semaphores and mutex, they are to use in multi-thread applications, so I suppose that you need to make a server that serve to multiple clients but using threads and so, semaphores.

You need to understand yourself how and why semaphores + mutex works and their differences, later that you will found a lot of examples about servers that works with multi-threads and you will be pointed about how to modify your current server.

Small tutorial:
http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/posixsem.html

And 2 examples:
http://www.minek.com/files/unix_examples/semab.html
http://refactormycode.com/codes/1237-using-semaphores-in-c-and-forking-processes